# How to animate a element that cover full screen width and not overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I apply some animation on `p` Elements , and want to make a marquee like effect,Somewhat they will animate but they goes out of screen or overflow.

I searched a lot,but nothing find exact ,only with Css3.

I have to define screen width inside `translateX(screen_width)` for having this effect.

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);  // Now i am using but fails
```

[**My fiddle of animation**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/tbe2N/1/)

*Do you have any Idea ,how I achieve this task without JavaScript ?*

[image: Code It Screen]

I add `JavaScript` tag in my question for only to get attention, if any scriptwriter Knows `Css 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this. It might be a bit over complicated but it is pure HTML and CSS.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/tbe2N/2/)**

By animating the `<span>` position within the `<p>`between `left: 0` and `left: 100%` while also using translate to move the `<span>` its full length to left, `translate(-100%)`. As the element will be positioned relative to its closest parent you need to specify `position: relative` for `<p>` and `position: absolute` for the `<span>`

The `&nbsp;` is only used to make sure the `<p>`retains its height even though the `<span>` inside has `position: absolute`

**CSS animation**

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
    0% {
        left: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
    }
}
```

**CSS for `<p>`and text**

```
p {
    margin:5px;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
}
p:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
    font-size:100px;    
}
p:nth-child(1) span {
    -webkit-animation: move 2s cubic-bezier(.47, .49, .47, .49) infinite alternate;
}
```

**HTML for text**

```
<div id='bgcont'>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<span>Gnome</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<span>Testfile</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<span>Myfilenew</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<span>Textshadow</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @AshishMishra I updated my answer with an attempt to explain how it works